# JS Translation not working

Tags: localisation, magento2.3.0

I'm having an issue with some translations in Magento 2 2.3.0. My store is in french, most of the text works fine.

It seems that the problem occurs only with content that come from JS (AJAX and template).

Example:
`<span data-bind="i18n: 'View and Edit Cart'">View and Edit Cart</span>`
I have the same problem with the state/province in the shipping calculation, it's in the wrong locale.

If I check in js-translation.json, there's around 300 translations and "View and Edit Cart" is one of them. I don't know where does these translations come from, my translation CSV has +9k terms.

I tried switching between dev and prod mode to see if the generation changed, but same thing.

Also, between every attempt, I ran these commands

```
rm -rf var/generation/* var/di/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* 
var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*;

bin/magento setup:upgrade;
bin/magento setup:di:compile;
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=[my theme] fr_CA -f;
bin/magento cache:flush;
bin/magento indexer:reindex;
```

Magento: Community Edition 2.3.0
PHP: 7.2.13

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out, kinda.

The problem with "View and Edit Cart" seems to have fixed itself somehow, I didn't change anything and just started to show up in the right language.

For popup massage `You added %1 to your shopping cart.`, I'm guessing it was changed in a patch because now there's a url on the "cart", so it's now `You added %1 to your <a href=""%2"">shopping cart</a>.` so it was never translated. (I could be wrong about this).

For the state/province translations, I found out that you need to make them in the database by hand in the table `directory_country_region_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Check in below path if the translation is getting updated

> app/code/Magento/Checkout/i18n/fr_CA.csv

Comment: `app/code/Magento` does not exists, my translations are in `app/i18n/imaginaerum/fr_ca/dictionary.csv` and it never get updated by Magento, only by me.